# how to display controllers dynamically in web api based on user/credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api with four controllers.From the four controllers,i need to give a user access to only that one controller but ensure other users are able to access the remaining controllers.

I have used  [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)] attribute but wanted to have a better way to manage the controllers dynamically.The web api is accessed by two different users and i want one of the users to access only  a certain controller only.Any idea  how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify users and roles [in the `Authorize` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api) on your controllers and actions.  For example:

```
// Restrict by user:
[Authorize(Users="Alice,Bob")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
}

// Restrict by role:
[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
}
```

These can be places at the class level or at the action method level.

Comment: if i add this,a user will still see the api definitions  but when making a request its when the request will be validated.Is it possible to hide the help page for that particular user so that they dont see api definitions of other controllers?

Comment: @JohnKim: In what way do they "see" the API definitions?  And why is it a problem?

Comment: the problem is because their are other controllers which they are not  supposed to see with their definitions.My plan is  to provide them the URL  and functions in a document i will prepare which lists the actions and url

Comment: in this way,i had envisioned to give them a document which has the api definitions myself as the api contains other controllers and functions which they are not supposed to see.

Comment: @JohnKim: So when you create that document, don't include the API endpoints that you don't want to tell them.  A document that you manually create has nothing to do with Web API.